# Problem with the Synaptic Package Manager for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, updates

For the last two years, I have not been able to do handle any changes, update or install new software as there is a major issue with the Synaptic Package Manager and also a similar situation occurs are the terminal level.

I cannot even update nor upgrade Ubuntu.
Everything seems to be blocked by the following errors:

```
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/www.iri.upc.edu_cuik_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.

W: Target Packages (partner/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4

W: Target Packages (partner/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4

W: Target Packages (partner/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4

W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en_CA) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4

W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4

W: Target DEP-11 (partner/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4

W: Target DEP-11-icons (partner/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
```

What should I do to repair this issue?

Comment: I'm guessing either delete line 4 from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list` or delete line 45 from `/etc/apt/sources.list` would fix the warnings, although not the "E" error at the top

Comment: Since 16.04 is EOL in April and it is time for an upgrade as there will be no more support or upgrades I suggest the following. Save all important data and a fresh install of 18.04 or better 20.04 as 21.04 comes in April.

Comment: Fix your repositories and then run `sudo do-release-upgrade` to get 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Canonical, the maker of Ubuntu will continue to support 16.04 through Extended Security Maintenance until April 2024. Ask Ubuntu is currently trying to change policy to make 16.04 off topic. ESM is free and not too hard to set up. I discus a little bit about activating it at this link: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19510/is-ubuntu-14-04-off-topic-on-ask-ubuntu/19529#19529 You can vote to continue Ask Ubuntu support for ESM versions of Ubuntu here: https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19545/43926